# Setting ip on interface using C code

Tags: linux, usb, ip, device-driver, ioctl

When i tried to set ip on usb0 interface(created due to USB gadget drivet) using ioctl in C code,it is throwing "permission denied" error.If i try to make usb0 "up" in C, it is showing "No such file or directory". Can anyone suggest me how to fix this?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your user has sufficient rights, does he? Did you try running as root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran my code executable with super user privileges and it worked successfully.